# Better way to write Linq Where statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am confuse about some multiple filter in `Linq` query.

Like this :

```
var OrderList = (from o in db.Order
                 where ( o.OrderType == 1 && 
                 (( (o.Status & 1) != 0) || ((o.Status & 2) != 0)) )
                 || ( o.OrderType == 2 && 
                 (( (o.Status & 3) != 0) || ((o.Status & 4) != 0)) )
                 orderby o.OrderID descending
                 select new
                 {
                    Name = o.Name
                 }).ToList();
```

Filter in `Linq` look ugly and not easy to read.

Have a better way to rewrite this ?

Comment: your formatting is pretty bad but if you replace your Bitwise `int` with an enumerable you will make this much easier to read, also will allow the use of the `HasFlags` functionality https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps you could make it a method?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using `Linq to SQL` , but I think these things had 
many similarities.

Comment: thank you @MikeT , `HasFlags` are so convenient and make code can be read easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Status` is a numeric value type (like `int` or `uint` or `long` etc..) and has no custom implementation of the `&` operator, `&` performs a *bitwise AND* with its operands.

So `((o.Status & 1) != 0) || ((o.Status & 2) != 0)` is the same as `(o.Status & 3) != 0`. It only tests if at least one of the two least significant bits are set. (Note that the bits of `3` are `0011`).

Accordingly `(o.Status & 3) != 0) || (o.Status & 4) != 0` is the same as `(o.Status & 7) != 0` (the bits of `7` are `0111`).

So you can simplify the condition to this:

```
 (o.OrderType == 1 && (o.Status & 3) != 0) ||
 (o.OrderType == 2 && (o.Status & 7) != 0)
```

---

But this is only a simplification... *Readability* lies in the eye of the *reader*. It may be appropriate to use an `enum` for the `Status` field instead:

```
[Flags]
public enum States
{
    FirstBit = 1, // use self-explaining names here
    SecondBit = 2,
    ThirdBit = 4
}

// condition
(o.OrderType == 1 && (o.Status.HasFlag(States.FirstBit) || o.Status.HasFlag(States.SecondBit)) ||
(o.OrderType == 2 && (o.Status.HasFlag(States.FirstBit) || o.Status.HasFlag(States.SecondBit) || o.Status.HasFlag(States.ThirdBit)))
```

This is longer, but may be more readable if the names are self-explaining.

Comment: you are correct that in this case the `&` is being used for bitwise comparison, but its a little misleading to says that is what `&` does, especially as its overrideable

Comment: @MikeT you're right, I was assuming `Status` to be (something like) an `int` and that there are no overloads. I added this assumption to my answer.